# Is there a way to specify the command line width in octave?

Tags: python, command-line, octave

I would like to use octave as a "calculator" in a python script. Currently I am running octave like so:

```
octave -q --eval 'some code'
```

and read the stdout to interpret the results.
However, I am running into problems once matrices reach a certain width so that octave starts to output them with column numerations like so:

```
ans =

 Columns 1 through 5:

   6.6264e-01   2.6142e-01   9.2413e-01   1.6814e-01   6.3117e-01      

Columns 6 and 7:

   6.6392e-01   4.0483e-01
```

which makes the interpreting of the result a little harder.

Is there a way to tell octave not to split up the printing of results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split_long_rows ()` command should be able to change this behavior.  From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Matrices.html#doc-split_long_rows),

> Query or set the internal variable that controls whether rows of a matrix may be split when displayed to a terminal window

Comment: Could you give an example or how to use `split_long_rows`? If I do `split_long_rows(0)` then only the `Columns 1 through 5:` part will be skipped and the matrix is still displayed in multiple rows. But it works great within python!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is any way to get the output without it printing a newline, however it should be fairly easy to parse.  If you need help, try it out then post a new question with your code and I'll take a look.